# Encrypt file with AES-128 in PHP and decrypt it in Android

Tags: php, android, encryption, aes

I need to encrypt a file using AES-128 in PHP and decrypt it in Android.

I am using the following code. I have successfully encrypted and decrypted it using PHP code, but I need to decrypt it using Android from my app.

PHP code:

```
$key= "asdfghjklzxccvbn";   
$in_filename = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
$aes_filename =$target_dir."encry_".$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
$decry_filename =$target_dir."decry_".$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];

//encrypt file
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$iv = '1234567890123456';

$fin = fopen($in_filename, "rb");
$fcrypt = fopen($aes_filename, 'wb');
fwrite($fcrypt, $iv);
$opts = array('iv'=>$iv, 'key'=>$key, 'mode'=>'cbc');
stream_filter_append($fcrypt, 'mcrypt.rijndael-128', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE,     $opts);
while (!feof($fin))
{
    fwrite($fcrypt, fread($fin, 8192));
}
fclose($fcrypt);
fclose($fin);
```

My Android code for decrypt encrypted file:

```
 // encripted file stored in android device for decrypt
 String uri= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
 uri=uri+"/encry_file.mp4";
 File file = new File(uri.toString());
 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
 spec =getIV();

 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/decrypted.mp4");
 SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec("asdfghjklzxccvbn".getBytes(),
          "AES");
 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
 cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks, spec);
 CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);

 int b;
 byte[] d = new byte[8192];
 while ((b = cis.read(d)) != -1) {
    fos.write(d, 0, b);
 }
 fos.flush();
 fos.close();
 cis.close();
```

get iv function

```
public AlgorithmParameterSpec getIV() {
    byte[] iv = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6 };
    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec;
    ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    return ivParameterSpec;
}
```

android code will generate a file but it not readable. please check my code is am doing the right codes or if it contain any problem. please help me to solve it

Comment: i dint get you. please make it specific.. am new to this thing. Where should i make the change and what

Answer (score 1):

The mode and padding do not match. You're using AES/CBC/ZeroPadding (Java notation) in PHP, but in Java you're using `Cipher.getInstance("AES")` which (probably) defaults to `Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding")`. Always use a fully qualified cipher description:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/ZeroPadding", "BC");
```

(That doesn't solve the problem.)

You're not using the same IV. The character '1' and the byte 1 are not the same thing, because a '1' is actually the byte 49.

```
byte[] iv = { 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54 };
```

Since BouncyCastles/SpongyCastles `ZeroPadding` is not exactly the same as mcrypt's zero padding, you should use `Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");` in order to parse the last 16 bytes of the decryption and remove the trailing 0x00 bytes.

Here is a way of doing that in your case:

```
int b;
byte[] d = new byte[8192];
byte[] p = null;
int holdOff;
while ((b = cis.read(d)) != -1) {
    holdOff = Math.max(b - cipher.getBlockSize(), 0);
    if (p != null) {
        fos.write(p, 0, p.length);
        Arrays.fill(p, 0);
    }
    if (p == null) {
        p = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
    }
    System.arraycopy(d, holdOff, p, 0, p.length);

    fos.write(d, 0, holdOff);
}

// here p contains the end of the plaintext followed by padding bytes
// remove padding:
int i = cipher.getBlockSize() - 1;
while(i >= 0 && p[i] == 0) {
    i--;
}
// write remaining bytes
fos.write(Arrays.copyOf(p, i+1), 0, i+1);

fos.flush();
fos.close();
cis.close();
```

The idea is that you hold off writing the last 16 bytes to the file and process them separately, because the last 16 byte of the decrypted file may contain 0x00 bytes that you need to remove.

---

#### Other considerations:

- Always generate the IV randomly for each encryption. It doesn't have to be secret, but it has to be unpredictable. You can send it along with the ciphertext for example by putting it in front of the ciphertext.
- Authenticate your the ciphertexts by running an HMAC over it (encrypt-then-MAC). Before you attempt a decryption, you need to check the MAC on the receiver side to see if it was manipulated on the way.

Comment: i have changed my android code as per your comment, but still not working.

Comment: Are there any errors? If there is a file, how does the resulting file differ from the expected file? Is the length the same? Do the first, the last or all bytes differ?

Comment: i cant able  use "ZeroPadding" it throws exception .

Comment: my encrypted file is "encry_file.mp4" its stored in device memory for testing and i need to create a decrypted file "decrypted.mp4" from it

Comment: You may need to specify "NoPadding" instead of "ZeroPadding" and remove the trailing 0x00 bytes yourself, but it should be easier to just include SpongyCastle.

Comment: i got it wat you mean but , i tried amy codes but desnt work for me . could you please send me some codes whre i need to change. i know i have to remove the last 0x00 from my encrypted file . but dont know how. please help

Comment: @Maarten Thanks! I new that Bouncy's ZeroPadding always pads, but I wasn't sure if it errors if it the last byte is not a 0x00 byte. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @VivekPPillai I've added a manual unpadding version for your streaming case. Let me know if there is a problem with that.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Hmm, tested against the latest version I don't bug out, so manual unpadding does not seem needed (but manual padding does seem to be required). Sorry about that one.

Comment: @ArtjomB. still its not working for me. I am getting a decrypted file but its not working. I have posted another question please check it. [php decryption code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207766/equivalent-android-code-for-aes-file-decryption-from-php)